# pass value to custom allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to construct a custom allocator to allocate from my own data pool.
I started with some sample code from the Microsoft site that seemed to be a minimal implementation of a custom allocator.

Original code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985953.aspx:

```
template <class T>  
struct Mallocator  
{  
    typedef T value_type;  
    Mallocator() noexcept {} //default ctor not required by STL  

    // A converting copy constructor:  
    template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept {}  
    template<class U> bool operator==(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return false;  
    }  
    T* allocate(const size_t n) const;  
    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept;  
};  

template <class T>  
T* Mallocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const  
{  
    if (n == 0)  
    {  
        return nullptr;  
    }  
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))  
    {  
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();  
    }  
    void* const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));  
    if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }  
    return static_cast<T*>(pv);  
}

template<class T>  
void Mallocator<T>::deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept  
{  
    free(p);  
}
```

I need to add state to the allocator, which I am passing in on construction.

I have fundamentally gotten everything to function, but have questions about whether I have done things the 'proper' way.

Modified code:

```
template <class T>  
struct Mallocator  
{  
    typedef T value_type;  
    Mallocator() noexcept {} //default ctor not required by STL
```

## 1 - Added this constructor to pass in a pointer to my allocator...

```
    Mallocator(my_allocator* cust_alloc) noexcept : _cust_alloc(cust_alloc) {}

    // A converting copy constructor:  
    //template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept {}
```

## 2 - modify copy constructor...

```
    template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&src) noexcept 
    {
        // this does not work:
        // _cust_alloc = src._cust_alloc;

        // this seems ugly, but does work...
        _cust_alloc = const_cast<Mallocator<U>&>(src).custom_allocator();
    }

    template<class U> bool operator==(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return false;  
    }  
    T* allocate(const size_t n) const;  
    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept;
```

## 3 - add accessor for allocator, because of copy constructor problem...

```
    my_allocator* custom_allocator(){ return _cust_alloc; }
```

## 4 - add pointer to my custom allocator...

```
private:
    my_allocator *_cust_alloc;

};
```

## 5 - Call my allocator here, instead of malloc...

```
template <class T>  
T* Mallocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const  
{  
    if (n == 0)  
    {  
        return nullptr;  
    }  
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))  
    {  
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();  
    }  

    void* const pv = _cust_alloc->allocate(n * sizeof(T));
    if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }  
    return static_cast<T*>(pv);  
}
```

## 6 - Call my allocator here to deallocate...

```
template<class T>  
void Mallocator<T>::deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept  
{  


    _cust_alloc->deallocate(p);
//        free(p);  
}
```

While this is all working at this point, I have questions as to whether things could or should have been done differently.

Question 1 - I found that I needed to add my member variable to the copy constructor.  This caused a problem of accessing my member variable when it was private.  I initially found this unusual, but I missed the fact that the copy constructor uses 'U', not 'T'.  I'm presuming that (as the comment in the original code might indicate) I am copying from an allocator of a different type here, which means I am copying a different class, which explains why I can't 'see' the private member directly.  To resolve this, I added an accessor and const_casted it.  This felt like a lot of trouble, and I was tempted to just make the member variable public.  Is there a better way to form this part of the code?  An explanation of the significance of 'T' and 'U' might be helpful too.

Question 2 - In my research while writing this, I noticed references to move constructors, perfect forwarding, etc.  I am not familiar enough to know what the nuances of creating and writing a move constructor.  Further, I don't know if one is needed, unless there is an issue with the default move constructor not getting my private member variable moved.  I'm not sure if or when the move constructor would be called in the context of STL containers.

In the context of what I am doing, is something like this needed, and how is it correctly formed?

```
template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&& src) noexcept
{
    return std::forward<U>(src);
}
```

Question 3 - in general, is there some 'accepted' way to 'add state' to a custom allocator that is better than what I did?  (am I totally missing it here, or am I on the right track?)

Comment: Your getter can be `const` (to avoid the `const_cast`).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Thanks, that makes the copy constructor look better.